# python data class default value for str to None

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass like this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class DataClassCard:
    rank: str = None
    suit: str
```

I am getting an error saying:

```
TypeError: non-default argument 'suit' follows default argument
```

Is there anyway to set this default value?

Finally calling:

```
queen_of_hearts = DataClassCard(suit = 'a')
queen_of_hearts.rank
```

Comment: I highly doubt that the code you presented here is the same code generating the exception. You surely missed the ` = None` part on the second property `suit`.

Comment: Yeah. Jinx. Your edit is your problem and implies the solution.

Comment: Can I only give default for specific items and not all ?

Comment: Yes, but that was not your question: *Is there anyway to set this default value?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields with a default value must come after any fields without a default. Just put suit above